# JavaScript : Please Explain this weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, scope, executioncontext

Just Started learning about JS.

**CASE-1** Please look at the below given image.

[image: image 1]

**My Understanding for this behavior** : JS interpreter on reaching line 9 which commands to execute function a(); will create a new execution context for function a (or we can say allocate memory in heap for execution context which is an object and point ***this*** to it, right ??). Now i know that interpreter will first go through the whole function body and will allocate space for variable declarations and function declaration,  in the execution context created in heap. This is evident from the right side of the image where in local Scope we have a reference variable *b* to the lambda of function. And now after having a pass through whole function body interpreter will execute code. Now since we  already have the function *b*  stored in *a*'s execution context (or *a*'s execution context knows about *b*),it will execute it. (This is what hoisting is, right ??)
So far so good. But,

Now look at this image :

Now if according to my concepts which i mentioned above, 
On right side inside Local we must have a variable *b* referencing to function lambda, but its not.

What am i missing ??
Is my concepts wrong ?? 
Is it because of Chrome console ??
Can you explain this behavior ??

[image]

**CASE-2** : Ok Then i did another experiment to know the behavior of Interpreter :

[image]
[image]

In both of the above given images, we have space allotted to variable *a* referencing to lambda of function, in both cases. This is completely opposite behavior to case-1.

Can you explain this behavior ??

Small Request (If you can..): If you can use the terms stack/heaps/memory/execution context object/link/pointers instead of Lexical environment, scopes, closures, chain etc etc it will be much preferred since they all are quite confusing. Its easy for me to understand things using above mentioned terms.

Comment: Sounds like if the function is never referenced, it gets optimized away

Comment: But then why it didn't happen in last case ??.

Comment: You mean with `a`? It's global, so it can still be referenced. But `b` has no possibility of being referenced in case 1 given the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing strange here. V8 compiles JavaScript directly into machine code. As a result, unreachable code, such as function b, is removed when it is never referenced. This is a common property of almost every compiler.

> What am i missing ?? Is my concepts wrong ?? Is it because of Chrome console ?? Can you explain this behavior ??

In this code snippet, which is different than the specific example of case-1, namely in that the call to `b` has been removed, the `b` function has been removed by the compiler. As a result, you do not see any reference to it in the debugger.

> **case-2**

In your examination of case-2, you overlook the fact that the debugger is stopped in the wrong place to analyze the interior scope of `function a`. As a result, you see `a` in the debugging window and that is it.

**Your understanding section**

> JS interpreter on reaching line 9 which commands to execute function a(); will create a new execution context for function a (or we can say allocate memory in heap for execution context which is an object and point this to it, right ??)

Not entirely.

- line 9: execute function a() [correct]
- create an execution context for function a [correct]
- allocate memory in heap [incorrect]
- execution context is an object [correct]
- point this to it [incorrect]

The execution context is an object, however, the compiled function is a static function frame stored on the stack. The `this` binding is a separate value which does not reference the execution context, but instead provides an entrance for variable scoping.

> Now i know that interpreter will first go through the whole function body and will allocate space for variable declarations and function declaration, in the execution context created in heap.

This is incorrect. As noted, the interpreter is working on compiled code. This code already has an established memory footprint. A pointer is created on the heap which points to the compiled code in the stack.

> This is evident from the right side of the image where in local Scope we have a reference variable b to the lambda of function.

`b` is not a lambda function, that would have been `var b = () => console.log('Hello i am B');`, and would *not* have been hoisted. That aside, under the hood, `a` is just a nested context. `b` is also compiled, and its static reference is just a component of the already compiled `a`. Scoping and memory storage are two very different concepts.

> And now after having a pass through whole function body interpreter will execute code. Now since we already have the function b stored in a's execution context (or a's execution context knows about b),it will execute it. (This is what hoisting is, right ??)

This code is direct, so the interpreter would create a pointer on the heap, and immediately execute the compiled code on the stack. `a` is executed, then inside of `a`, `b` is executed as noted above.

Hoisting is simply moving declarations to the tops of scopes for `function` declarations and `var` declarations, but not `const` or `let`. Hoisting simply makes your first example equivalent to this:

```
function a(){
    function b(){
        console.log('Hello i am B')
    }
    console.log('Heloo')
    b()
}
a()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for detailed answer.
From Your explanation about case-2, it seems either you misunderstand the question or maybe i made some error in writing question leading to confusion, anyways question  in case-2 is if compiler do optimization as you said  then function a is also not referenced so in that case we must not see it in debug window. Because we are running compiled code.

Comment: What you see in the debug window is the result of the interpreter, not the compiler.

Comment: In any event, if you curious why `a` shows up that is because variables declared at the global level become properties of the window object, thus having a reference.

Comment: Thanks that cleared the doubt.
Also :
"The this binding is ........ an "ENTRANCE" for variable scoping.". Can you please elaborate on this? "Entrance" ?

Also small request : Can you please share some reference links from which you gained  system level knowledge about JS  like compiled code, static function frame, pointers in heap, "this is entrance to variable scoping", etc etc you got the point. I had only found Dmitry Soshnikov's blogs to be useful.Thank you very much.